# Monitor MSMQ

Tags: msmq, cluster-computing

I'm trying to monitor a remote private msmq in a Server 2003 cluster with the MSMQ Local Admin API and the mgmtinfo.exe utility. I can list the queues on the clustered resource with the command:

```
mgmtinfo.exe server-name machine
```

but cannot get information about the individual queues. I'm having difficulty crafting a correct format name:

```
mgmtinfo.exe queue=<FORMAT NAME>
```

What is the format name for private (clustered) queues? I have seen references to guid's but I can't find one associated withe queue... Does anyone have a suggestion? Thanks for the help!

Comment: I tried all the format names I could think of (plus the ones below) I've given up on the Admin API and written a C# program to count messages on queues and issue alerts etc.

Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

> FormatName:DIRECT=OS:servername\private$\queuename

Answer (score 0):

If the queue is a private queue: .\private$\YourCustomQueue

I think it is .\system$\ and .\outgoing$ for the other queues.